# How to provide GET request using http module

Tags: node.js, express, http

I am able to write code using node and express for the below request:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/1
```

The code is :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

I want to do the same using http module:

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8000); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

What is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to:

- Read `req.method` and see it's the method you expect, and if not error.
- Read `req.url`, and use a path matching library, such as `path-to-regexp` or regular expression to validate the path and extract parameters.

If you want actual code samples for this, read the source of these frameworks.

Comment: Can you please share me code sample. I am trying to check this `https://nodejs.org/api/http.html` but I am not able to find correct approach to solve this.

Comment: @learner there is no built in way to do this automatically for you. You are basically making your own mini-framework. I also don't want to write all the code for you. If you dont' want to write the code, use a framework.

Comment: I have tried it, but the chai test script is failing now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318987/getting-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-while-running-testcase This is the issue I am getting, can you please help me how to fix this.